# HTML input pattern type for NN:NN

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to sort out a regex pattern for any positive number, *NN:NN*. Its for the user to enter in the duration of exercise *HH:MM* where MM is <60.

For eg: 22:22 , 99:59, 01:00, 66:00 but not 00:00

So far I have tried this pattern="([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-9][0-9]" but its only for 24 hour time.

```
pattern="([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-9][0-9]"
```

I expected 55:55 but it does not allow me to go above number 2 on first digit ('2'_:__)

Comment: Why do you allow minutes higher than 59?

Comment: yes it should not @Barmar , what could be the code for that

Comment: Why not use [`<input type="time" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)?

Comment: much complicated, comes with am/pm and not in correct format

Comment: @Rino whatever, its entirely your call. There's nothing complicated about it though. Just drop the input on the page and you're done. The format of the submitted value is always in 24h format but the time picker rendered may ask for am/pm depending on the browser and user's locale. [More info here if you care.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the character class `[01]?[0-9]` also matches 00 as well as `[0-9][0-9]`

One option is to use a negative lookahead to check if what is on the right is not 00:00 and make use of word boundaries `\b`

```
\b(?!00:00)[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?!00:00)` Assert what is on the right is not 00:00
- `[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]` match 2 digits `:` number 00 till 59
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jFHyYa/1)

```js
const regex = /\b(?!00:00)[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]\b/;
[
  "22:22",
  "99:59",
  "99:60",
  "01:00",
  "66:00",
  "00:00"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + ": " + regex.test(s)))
```

Comment: perfect!, what would be the explanation for your answer?

Comment: @Rino I have added an explanation. Note that if you do want to match the minutes up till 59 you could use https://regex101.com/r/hjwpry/1

Comment: that answer does not allow me to go above 23 for hours field and accepts input like 2:59

Comment: @Rino But the pattern `\b(?!00:00)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\b
` in the answer does https://regex101.com/r/0A88CT/1

Comment: @Rino That was just in case you did not want to go over 59 minutes. I can remove the comment if you want.

Comment: the original answer is correct except i want the MM field to not be > 59

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
/^(?=.*[1-9]+)\d{2}\:\d{2}$/;
```

Explanation

`(?=.*[1-9]+)`  Lookahead for at least 1 non zero digit

`\d{2}\` To match any 2 digits in hour part

`\:[0-5][0-9]` To match minutes with max 59 after `:`

Here's a JavaScript implementation of the RegEx

```js
let re = /^(?=.*[1-9]+)\d{2}\:[0-5][0-9]$/;
console.log("00:00 => ",re.test("00:00"));
console.log("01:00 => ",re.test("01:00"));
console.log("00:10 => ",re.test("00:10"));
console.log("11:00 => ",re.test("11:00"));
console.log("33:44 => ",re.test("33:44"));
console.log("66:60 => ",re.test("66:60"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 2 parts to this, it may be better to validate this in 2 parts instead of 1. If you try to do too much in a regex, it will get unwieldy and impossible to understand. It'll also become too difficult to test reasonably.

The first part of this is a positive assertion.  You want to make sure you have 2 numbers followed by a colon and 2 more numbers:

```js
/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/
```

To limit the second group of digits to valid minutes (e.g. something less than 59) the following regex will work:

```js
/^\d{2}:[0-5][0-9]$/
```

The second is a negative assertion. You want to make sure it's not 00:00. Depending on the framework you're using, there's generally an easy way to add this second check. If you're not using a framework, you would listen for changes to the input and validate it on a change.